# How to validate that each wagtail page will have a unique slug?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have several models that inherit from `Page` and I'd like to check that each page that is being added/edited has a **unique** slug. Is there a way to validate it without overriding the `clean` method?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case someone come across the same issue:

After reading the [wagtail hooks documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/hooks.html), it is possible to register `before_create_page` and `before_edit_page` hooks and do the the slug's uniqueness validation there.
One possible solution could be:

in *wagtail_hooks.py*

```
from wagtail.core import hooks
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from django.shortcuts import redirect
...
...
@hooks.register("before_edit_page")
def before_edit_page(request, page):
    return validate_unique_slug(request, current_page=page)


@hooks.register("before_create_page")
def before_create_page(request, parent_page, page_class):
    return validate_unique_slug(request, parent_page=parent_page)


def validate_unique_slug(request, current_page=None, parent_page=None):
    req_slug = request.POST.get("slug")

    if req_slug == None:
        return

    try:
        db_page = Page.objects.get(slug=req_slug)
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return

    is_create_action = current_page == None
    if is_create_action or db_page.id != current_page.id:
        from wagtail.admin import messages

        messages.error(
            request,
            f"The page could not be save, the slug {req_slug} is already in use.",
        )
        page_id = str(parent_page.id if is_create_action else current_page.id)
        to = f"/admin/pages/{page_id}/edit/"
        return redirect(to)
```